# How to access parent movieclip's variable from loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, loader, swfloader

I have a swf which load an external swf. The loader swf has a variable which i want to access from the loaded swf. I use `MovieClip(parent.parent).myVar` but it return this error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at card01_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

The loader swf has a custom Document Class which i think is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is the as of the main swf

```
    package 
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author chchrist
     */
    public class CardSender extends Sprite 
    {

        private var loader:Loader;
        private var viewButtonArray:Array;
        private var sendButtonArray:Array;
        private var cardContainer:Sprite;

        public var testVar:String

        public function CardSender() {

            testVar = "it worked!!!";
            init();
        }

        private function init() {
            viewButtonArray = [cardsenderMC.view01, cardsenderMC.view02, cardsenderMC.view03, cardsenderMC.view04];

            for each( var viewButton in viewButtonArray) {
                viewButton.buttonMode = true;
                viewButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onViewClick);
            }
        }

        private function onViewClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var cardName = "card"+e.target.name.substring(4)+".swf";
            loader = new Loader();
            loader.load( new URLRequest(cardName));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onCardInit);
        }

        private function onCardInit(e:Event):void {
            addChild(loader);
            var content:* = loader.content;
            content.closeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCloseClick);
        }

        private function onCloseClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            removeChild(loader);
        }

    }
}
```

and I am trying to access the test variable from the loaded swf with this code

```
trace(MovieClip(parent.parent).testVar);
```

**EDIT#2**

If I `addChild(loader)` not in the onCardInit but in the onViewClick and in the first frame of the loaded swf i have `Object(parent.parent).testVar` it works...but why it doesn't want to be inside the onCardInit function?

Comment: which one is throwing null - parent or parent.parent?

Comment: parent.parent is throwing null

Comment: what do u get for `trace(parent); - what's its data type?

Comment: That explains it - `Stage` is the parent of all parents - like Adam if you will. You can't access its parent - it doesn't have any. Where are you calling this from - loaded swf or loader swf?

Comment: If you are calling it from loaded swf, its parent (normally) would be the `Loader` object that loaded it. Hard to say anything without seeing any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just one `loader` variable and you're creating four `Loader` instances and assigning them to it - so if you are clicking all four of them in quick succession, the `loader` variable will effectively contain the `Loader` object corresponding to the last click. All your `addChild` calls will act on that same `Loader` object - the others will not be added and their parents will continue to be `null`

Make the following changes to the code:

```
private function onCardInit(e:Event):void 
{
    addChild(LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).loader);
    var content:DisplayObject = loader.content;
    trace(content);
    trace(content.closeButton);
    content.closeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCloseClick);
}

private function onCloseClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    trace(e.currentTarget);//should be the closeButton
    trace(e.currentTarget.parent);//should be the loaded swf
    trace(e.currentTarget.parent.parent);//should be the Loader object that loaded it

    //The following will work only if last three traced correctly
    removeChild(e.currentTarget.parent.parent);
}
```

Answer to the following update in the question:

> If I `addChild(loader)` in the `onViewClick` instead of `onCardInit`, then `Object(parent.parent).testVar` in the first frame of the loaded swf works. Why doesn't it work if I addChild inside the onCardInit function?

Again, that might be because you are adding a different `loader` object - are you clicking on more than one viewbuttons? Click on a view-button and wait till it is loaded to see it working.

Comment: Yes i agree but my real problem now is how to access from the loaded swf the testVar variable.

Comment: Where are you trying to access it? from the constructor of document class? event handler? button class? - I think some code would help

Comment: from the first frame of the loaded swf

Comment: I click on a view button which loads a card and takes up all the stage. The only way to remove the card is to hit the close button which is inside the card and call the onCloseClick function. So there is no way that multiple loader objects exist. I want the loaded card to be able to access some varialbes from the main swf which is loaded.

Comment: what does `trace(this);` trace - does it work correctly - does it trace name of the document class of the loaded SWF? If it does, there is no way that this.parent will trace Stage - because you are adding it to the loader. The display list would look like - Stage - loader SWF's root - loader object - loaded swf.

Answer (score 2):

parent.parent is wrong.
try using:

```
MovieClip(MovieClip(e.currentTarget.parent).parent).myVar ;
```

You have to cast the first parent to some class like MovieClip and then get this new MovieClip's parent and then getting inside variable.

Answer (score 0):

try tracing parent and parent.parent, I'm sure it's because of an aditional "parent"

Answer (score 0):

loader.content is NOT a movieclip, so it doesn't have the same capabilities. try

myLoadedClip:MovieClip = MovieClip(loader.content);

then your myLoadedClip.parent.myVar should show up

you might want your handler to fire on a Event.COMPLETE instead of on an Event.INIT

Answer (score 0):

This only line code in loaded swf resolves it! ;)

**MovieClip(MovieClip(parent.parent).root).play();**